# base template class can't be constructed

Tags: c++, gcc

I have the following template base class:

```
template <class K>
class Base
{
protected:
    Base(int tableSize) : m_tableSize(tableSize) {}
    int doBaseWork(const K& data);
private:
    int m_tableSize;
};
```

And this template class inherits it:

```
template <class K>
class Derived : public Base<K>
{
public:
    Derived (int tableSize) : Base(tableSize){}
private:
    int doDerivedWork();
};
```

Then somewhere in the code i use:

```
Derived<int> testDerived(10);
```

When compiling with gcc i get the following error

```
class 'Derived<K>' does not have any field named 'Base'
```

What am i doing wrong? it seems like gcc thinks i'm trying to initialize a member, but i'm just trying to initialize base.

Comment: Did you try `: Base<K>(tableSize) {}`?

Comment: This works. Is this something specific to gcc?

Comment: Not to GCC. It has a long explanation having to do with dependent names, class name injection, and so forth and so forth.

Comment: But it seems easily deducible from the code. Is it just there for consistency?

Comment: *"easily deducible from the code"* - Not as easy or deducible or even consistent as you might think.

Comment: @Yotam what if you want to inherit from several `Base<T>`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write template parameters

```
Base<K>(tableSize)
```